# Shell I/O redirection

Tags: c, linux, shell, redirect, io

Hi i'm trying to build a shell in c and i'm stuck with the i/o redirection part. I have to support multiple redirection such as "333sh: myprog < in_file > out_file" myprog is taking input from the in_file and the result will be redirected to the out_file and so on. Can you give me a  starting point? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the shell you're writing has the job of launching the processes `myprog` and somehow forcing it to read its input from `in_file` and write its output to `out_file`.

The first thing you'll want to do is parse the input. What this means is somehow represent inside your program the name of the process you want to launch, the filename to read in from, and the filename to write out to. Doing this basically requires tokenizing the string `myprog < in_file > out_file` and then coming up with some representation (like a struct) for what to do.

How to actually achieve redirection is pretty easy. To launch the process, I'm guessing you're going to `fork()` and then `execvp`. The thing to realize is that file descriptors are copied across forks and persist across execvps.

So basically in the shell, you use the `dup(2)` call to replace STDIN_FILENO with a file descriptor for `input_file` and replace STDOUT_FILENO with a file descriptor for `output_file`. Then fork, then execvp. After the fork, in the parent process (the shell) you'll want to restore the STDOUT and STDIN file descriptors to what they were before the fork, so you'll want to remember that information in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have printf and scanf (or other functions that work with stdin/stdout) replace them with the functions that receive an argument for the filename (fprintf/fscanf) and in that file argument put the io redirection file after opening it.